# Convert flat data to hierarchical with inner objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I faced with common issue converting simple flat data to hierarchical. I have found multiple topics about that but still can't get how to convert flat data exactly to necessary me hierarchical format

this my json

```
    [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sponsor",
    "description": null,
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Class",
    "description": null,
    "parentId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Study",
    "description": null,
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Site",
    "description": null,
    "parentId": 3
  }
]
```

and I need to get format like this

```
  [
    {
      "data":{
        "id": 1,
        "name":"Sponsor",
        "description":null,
        "parentId":"null"
      },
      "children":[
        {
          "data":{
            "id": 2,
            "name":"Class",
            "description":null,
            "parentId":"1"
          },
          "children":[
            {
              "data":{
                "id": 3,
                "name":"Study",
                "description":null,
                "parentId":"2"
              },
             "children": [
                {
                   "data":{ 
                     "id": 4,
                     "name":"Site",
                     "description":null,
                     "parentId":"3"
                   }
                 }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

this is my function

```
    flatToHierarchy(flat) {

    let roots = [];
    let all = {};

    flat.forEach(function (item) {
      all[item.id] = item
    });

    Object.keys(all).forEach(function (id) {
      let item = all[id];
      if (item.parentId === null) {
        roots.push(item)
      } else if (item.parentId in all) {
        let p = all[item.parentId];
        if (!('Children' in p)) {
          p.children = []
        }
        p.children.push(item)
      }
    });

    console.log(roots);
    return roots
  }
```

output

```
    [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sponsor",
    "description": null,
    "parentId": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Class",
        "description": "Together",
        "parentId": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Study",
            "description": "browsing data",
            "parentId": 2,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Site",
                "description": null,
                "parentId": 3,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
```

I'm pretty close to desire result. Could somebody to help me fix that ?

**Edited**

the right answer provided by **@Someone3**
this is slightly modified code for my needs

```
    flatToHierarchy (flat) {

    let roots = [];
    let all = {};
    let ids = [];

    flat.forEach(function (item) {
      let itemId = item.id;
      let convertedItem = function (id) {
        let newItem = {};
        newItem['data'] = id;
        return newItem;
      } ;
      all[itemId] = convertedItem(item);
      ids.push(itemId);
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      let id = ids[i];
      let convertedItem = all[id];
      let parentId = convertedItem.data.parentId;

      if (parentId === null) {
        roots.push(convertedItem);
      } else if (parentId in all) {
        let p = all[parentId];
        if (!('children' in p)) {
          p.children = []
        }
        p.children.push(convertedItem)
      }
    }
    return roots
  }
```

Comment: Your desired format is not the same as your json. And on your example format, each object has a different parent so they cannot be in the same `children: []` array

Comment: `flat.forEach(parent => parent.children = flat.filter(child => child.parentId === parent.id))`

Comment: and `'Children' !== 'children'`

Comment: or with linear runtime: `var root = flat.reduce(function(mapping, node){
 if(!(node.id in mapping)) mapping[node.id] = [];
 if(!(node.parentId in mapping)) mapping[node.parentId] = [];
 node.children = mapping[node.id];
 mapping[node.parentId].push(node);
 return mapping;
})[null];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is full source code for your situation. I modified and added a few lines from your source code.
**Note that this code assumes that parents are always inserted to this tree before their children do.** If this assumption is not always true then your code need to be changed more than this.

```
let flatData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sponsor",
    "description": null,
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Class",
    "description": null,
    "parentId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Study",
    "description": null,
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Site",
    "description": null,
    "parentId": 3
  }
];

function convertItem(item) {
  let newItem = {};
  newItem.data = item;  
  return newItem;
}

function flatToHierarchy(flat) {

    let roots = [];
    let all = {};
    let ids = [];

    flat.forEach(function (item) {
      let itemId = item.id;
      let convertedItem = convertItem(item);
      all[itemId] = convertedItem;
      ids.push(itemId);
    });

    // We use ids array instead of object to maintain its previous order.
    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      let id = ids[i];
      let convertedItem = all[id];
      let parentId = convertedItem.data.parentId;

      if (parentId === null) {
        delete convertedItem.data.parentId;
        delete convertedItem.data.id;
        roots.push(convertedItem);
      } else if (parentId in all) {
        let p = all[parentId];
        if (!('Children' in p)) {
          p.children = []
        }
        delete convertedItem.data.parentId;
        delete convertedItem.data.id;
        p.children.push(convertedItem)
      }
    };

    console.log(roots);
    return roots
  }

  flatToHierarchy(flatData);
```

We can factor out two deletes before push.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I accepted your answer because it helps me a lot, but I little bit modified it to fit my code

Answer (score 0):

How about my way?

```
function flatToHierarchy (flatData) {
  const tree = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(flatData)) // or using `cloneDeep` of lodash library to not side-effect with flatData

  tree.forEach((item) => {
      item.children = tree.filter((element) => element.parent_id === dept.id)
  });
  const roots = tree.filter((item) => item.parent_id === 0)
  return roots
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const flatToHierarchy = (inputArr, parent = null) => {

      const result = [];

      for(let i = 0; i<inputArr.length; i++) {
    
        if(inputArr[i].parentId === parent) {
          const dataObj = {
            data : {
                ...inputArr[i],
            }
          }

        const children = flatToHierarchy(inputArr, inputArr[i].id);

          if(children.length > 0) {
            dataObj.children = children;
          }

          result.push(dataObj);
         }
      }

    return result;
}
```